# In symfony2, the login action is showing me as logged out when I'm actually logged in

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

If a logged in user goes to the login action, I want to redirect them to another page. But I can't figure out how to detect whether the user is logged in or not while inside of the `loginAction` method. The security context in the login action make me seem logged out when I'm not.

As a test, I'm requesting both of the following pages while I'm logged into the site. Why can't I get access to the user in the login action?

Here's my login action:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $token = $this->get('security.context')->getToken();
    print_r(get_class($token));
        // Outputs "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken"
    print_r($token->getUser());
        // Outputs "anon."
}
```

Here is a generic action in the application, protected by the login:

```
public function regularAction()
{
    $token = $this->get('security.context')->getToken();
    print_r(get_class($token));
        // Outputs "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken"
    print_r(get_class($token->getUser()));
        // Outputs "Company\BaseBundle\Entity\User"
}
```

Here's my `security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Company\BaseBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:   sha1
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false
    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: Company\BaseBundle\Entity\User, property: user_name }
    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                post_only: true
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /
                use_referer: true
                failure_path: null
                failure_forward: false
                username_parameter: user_name
                password_parameter: password_hash
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                intention: authenticate
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
    acl:
        connection: default
```

**EDIT: I didn't think the rest of my firewalls were pertinent, but after reading ilanco's answer, I think they might be**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Company\BaseBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:   sha1
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: Company\BaseBundle\Entity\User, property: user_name }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
        password_reset:
            pattern:    ^/passwordreset/*$
            anonymous:  ~
        error_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/error/.*$
            anonymous:  ~
        unsupported_broswers:
            pattern:    ^/unsupported$
            anonymous:  ~
        security_question_firewall:
            pattern:  ^/user/(locked|security_question)/(new)*$
            anonymous:  ~
        api_firewall:
            pattern:  ^/api/.*$
            provider: main
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured API Area. Login with your regular credentials"
                provider: main
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                post_only: true
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /
                use_referer: true
                failure_path: null
                failure_forward: false
                username_parameter: user_name
                password_parameter: password_hash
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                intention: authenticate
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
    acl:
        connection: default
```

Following ilanco's suggestion, I removed this:

```
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~
```

and added this directly under the `providers` section:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But then I had a redirect loop error when I accessed /login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have struggled with this problem as well.

`/login` is not part of the main firewall, as such the user is not accessible there.

The way to solve this is to remove the custom firewall you have called `login_firewall` and allow access to `/login` through ACL.

Add the following code to your `security.yml`

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: In response to your answer, I edited the original post. Could you please look at it?

Comment: Put `access_control:` under `security:`, not `providers:`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this one - the problem with redirection loop is caused by the lack of access to the /login page. I've made only one firewall, set the access for anonymous: ~, defined access_control for non-users and voila!

```
security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: true
            anonymous: ~ 
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: Core\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
    encoders:
        Core\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm:   sha256
            iterations: 10
            encode_as_base64: true
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_SUPERADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```